# How to remove `undefined` value from an object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object like this

`const obj = {a: 123, b: 'text', c: [1,2,3]}`

I use it for route params, but `c` can be an empty array, I don't have to handle a and b because they surely will have value. Do I have to manually omit `c` from `obj`? making it only `{a: 123, b: 'text'}`?

Is there any way I don't have to manually omit the property from the object if the value is undefined?

Comment: The question is not clear to me.  What is your objective?  What is your problem?  There's nothing wrong with an object declaration containing an empty  array: `{a: 123, b: 'text', c: []}` in the Javascript sense, not sure what you are doing with that object though.

Comment: @jfriend00 is there any way I don't have to manually omit the property from the object if the value is undefined?

Comment: I don't understand what manually omit means?  How?  You either declare the `c` property or you don't.  If you're consuming the object, you can check if the `c` property exists or if the array is empty just fine.

Comment: You could do `delete obj.c;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `lodash`, you can use `omitBy`

`_.omitBy({a: 123, b: 'text', c: undefined}, _.isUndefined)`

Morever, you can combine many condition by chain

```
_({a:123,b:'text',c:undefined,d:null})
          .omitBy(_.isUndefined)
          .omitBy(_.isNull).value();
```

Or

You can introduce a function that help u omit undefined value for every objects

```js
const obj = {a: 123, b: 'text', c: undefined};

const omitObj = obj => Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
 if (obj[key] === undefined) {
    return acc;
 }
 acc[key] = obj[key];
 return acc;
}, {})


const newObj = omitObj(obj);
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: I can write this, I'm just curious is there any lib or wrapper or not, so that I don't have to write it manually

Comment: you can use `omitBy` of `lodash` to do that, just updated my answer

Comment: how to use lodash omitBy to omit if the value is empty array? this won't work ```_.omitBy({a: 123, c: []}, a => !a.length === 0)```

Comment: It should be like that `_.omitBy({a: 123, c: []}, a => a.length === 0)` without `!`

Comment: why do you want to use a library to solve this task? If you are certain that you are going to use something like lodash from now until forever in this project (or even to solve this problem), then that's fine, but this type of problem isn't a great use-case for a tool like lodash, and is abstracting you away from core JS principles. I'm not hating on your desire to use a tool, but I'm curious what your reasons are.

Comment: why not? lodash is a great lib, why write different code but solve the same thing? before es6 became a thing, lodash's ```get```,```filter``` abd ```reduce``` is used heavily, do you write pure for loop back in the day?

Answer (score 0):

In case you're not sure about the last param

just make a conditional statement

```
const obj = {a: 123, b: 'text', c: [1,2,3]}

var AnotherObj = obj
if (AnotherObj.c == undefined)
    delete AnotherObj.c
```

if obj.c is defined everything will be fine

else it will delete the third param from the object